# How to assign an integer value to an imageView in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android

I am creating a feedback app where a user has to click one of the 5 imageViews (1-5 rating) based on his/her experience. My primary aim is to extract the integer value of this rating from the imageView click and push it to a SQLite database.

I am trying to use `setTag()` and `getTag()` but to no avail. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

activity_main.xml -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="99dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="99dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="172dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="172dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="151dp"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/editTextPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextPersonName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="172dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="172dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="54dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Full Name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textViewName"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="92dp"
        android:layout_height="103dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="35dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="151dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="47dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="47dp"
        android:tag="1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewName"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="92dp"
        android:layout_height="103dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="60dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="64dp"
        android:tag="4"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView3"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_width="92dp"
        android:layout_height="103dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="46dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="46dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="64dp"
        android:tag="5"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.833"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView4"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="92dp"
        android:layout_height="103dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="48dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="48dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="63dp"
        android:tag="2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView1"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="92dp"
        android:layout_height="103dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="53dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="53dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="49dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="49dp"
        android:tag="3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="333dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="333dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="41dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="340dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="340dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="75dp"
        android:text="Were you satisfied with our hygiene standards?"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextPersonName" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainActivity.java -

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText name;
    ImageView oneStar;
    ImageView twoStar;
    ImageView threeStar;
    ImageView fourStar;
    ImageView fiveStar;
    Intent intent;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPersonName);
        oneStar = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        oneStar.setTag(1);
        oneStar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String username = name.getText().toString()+"\n";
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, (Integer) oneStar.getTag(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace oneStar.getTag() with view.getTag()

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the tag, and display it as a Toast message, the instead of casting it into an Integer object convert it to String using .toString method.

Comment: Thanks this worked for the toast. Let me try to push it into the database and see if it works. Will update in a while.

Answer (score 0):

Second parameter of Toast.makeText is interger, but you can't pass any integer. It must be the resource Id of a string (R.string.your_string). Remove "(Integer)" and it should solve your problem.

I don't know exactly what are your requirements and in case you missed it, there is a build in [rating bar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar)in Android. You can check the tutorial [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-use-ratingbar-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

it is less code and less error prone if you just add this to ImageView: android:onClick="imageViewClick", and create a handler in MainActivity like this:

```
        public void imageViewClick(View view) {
            String username = name.getText().toString()+"\n";
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, (Integer)view.getTag(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```